# Unity Colliders doesn’t work with deltaPosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to move my Player with offset. I’m using deltaPosition to get touch moves. But if I use deltaPosition, colliders doesn’t work. When I use different codes without deltaPosition colliders work but different codes not useful for my project. I used other RigidBody MovePosition  but not worked . Here is the codes:

```cs
void Update()

{

  İf(ınput.touchCount> 0)

{

  Touch touch_1 = Input.GetTouch(0);
İf(touch_1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)

{ 

  transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + touch_1.deltaPosition.x*speedModifier , transform.position.y + touch_1.deltaPosition.y*speedModifier);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem. All you got to do is changing ‘transform.position’ to ‘rigidbody.MovePosition’. It’ll make colliders work.